# HTML5 Canvas, excanvas.js & IE. Text not showing in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This simple Canvas script creates a rectangle with a border **and text**. It works in Chrome and FireFox.  But the text does not work in Internet Explorer 7.0.  I have included excanvas.js; for this reason the rectangle and border show up in IE 7. However, the text is not showing up in IE 7. I want to know if it is possible to get this simple script to work in IE 7 and 8?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function addBox(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context=c.getContext("2d"); 

        //Inner rectangle with shadow
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.shadowColor="brown";
        context.shadowBlur = 20;
        context.fillRect(402,227,96.5,48.5); 
        context.shadowColor = null; 
        context.shadowBlur = null;      

        //Outer Rectangle
        context.lineWidth = '5';
        context.strokeStyle='green';    
        context.strokeRect(400,225,100,50); //draws just the edges of a rectangle               

        //font
        context.font = '17px Arial';        
        context.textBaseline = 'top';  
        context.fillStyle    = 'black';
        context.fillText  ('hello', 433, 243);
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="addBox()"> 

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="500">Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas> <br />
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
        cxt4=c.getContext("2d");
        resetCanvas();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen [Issue 6](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=6) on the Google Code site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried this on mine and had the same results. Then I found that I was using an earlier revision of excanvas. Ran the code again with [this version](http://code.google.com/p/canvas-text/source/browse/trunk/excanvas.js?r=48) and it worked in IE8. Haven't tested on IE7 but with some luck it will work.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The  fillText is working when i changed excanvas.js file 
http://canvas-text.googlecode.com/svn-history/r48/trunk/excanvas.js

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to explain what you changed here, since external links tend to change, and see-this-link answers are not allowed.